Count on LEFT JOIN in SQL
I would like to know how can I get Count on LEFT JOIN in SQL.
Currently I have 3 tables :
rooms_messages



id
room_id
discussion_message_id
created_at




1
10
101
2024-07-16 12:30:45


2
20
102
2024-07-16 12:30:50


3
10
103
2024-07-16 12:32:45


4
20
104
2024-07-16 12:34:50


5
20
105
2024-07-16 12:36:50



discussions_messages (has many discussions_replies)



id
text




101
Hello


102
Test


103
Ok


104
Wow


105
Hello2



discussions_replies



id
discussion_message_id
text




201
103
Hello


202
103
Test



I use this query, to show the latest rooms_messages and attach the discussions_messages text. But the replies isn't correct:

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT rm.id as id, rm.created_at, rm.room_id,
           rm.discussion_message_id, dm.text, count(dm.id) as replies,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY rm.room_id ORDER BY rm.created_at DESC) rn
    FROM rooms_messages AS rm
    INNER JOIN discussions_messages AS dm ON rm.discussion_message_id = dm.id
    LEFT JOIN discussions_replies AS dr ON dm.id = dr.discussion_message_id
    GROUP BY dm.id
)

SELECT id, created_at, room_id, discussion_message_id, text, replies
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1

I would like to show the discussions_replies attach on discussions_messages.
I think the problem is on the line:
count(dm.id) as replies,
...
INNER JOIN discussions_messages AS dm ON rm.discussion_message_id = dm.id
LEFT JOIN discussions_replies AS dr ON dm.id = dr.discussion_message_id


Can you show the desired result?

Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots (how to format code in posts). Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Where does replies=3 come from for message ID 103? There are only 2 replies in discussion_replies.

The query is not well defined: OVER (PARTITION BY rm.room_id ORDER BY rm.created_at DESC) probably doesn't produce a unique sorting criteria.

Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Can you toss the CTE, OVER, etc, and simply have SELECT ... ORDER BY ... DESC LIMIT 1?

Use a second CTE to get the counts, instead of doing it in the same CTE that gets the last row.
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT rm.id as id, rm.created_at, rm.room_id,
           rm.discussion_message_id, dm.text,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY rm.room_id ORDER BY rm.created_at DESC) rn
    FROM rooms_messages AS rm
    INNER JOIN discussions_messages AS dm ON rm.discussion_message_id = dm.id
    LEFT JOIN discussions_replies AS dr ON dm.id = dr.discussion_message_id
), counts AS (
  SELECT room_id, IFNULL(COUNT(dr.id), 0) AS replies
  FROM rooms_messages AS rm
  INNER JOIN discussions_messages AS dm ON rm.discussion_message_id = dm.id
  LEFT JOIN discussions_replies AS dr ON dm.id = dr.discussion_message_id
  GROUP BY room_id
)

SELECT id, created_at, cte.room_id, discussion_message_id, text, replies
FROM cte 
JOIN counts ON cte.room_id = counts.room_id
WHERE rn = 1

DEMO

To make it executable remove GROUP BY dm.id and count(dm.id) as replies,; because of PARTITION BY rm.room_id it will show rows from discussions_messages and ROW_NUMBER() will count these rows per room. This is showing 3 because you have 1 message 101 in room 10 and also 1 message 103 in room 10, but you are showing room 10 twice because it has two discussion replies. Fiddle
Your joins were fine; the logic was incorrect; you overcomplicated it with an unnecessary window function.
Since you only need to count discussion replies per discussion messages, adjust the code (Fiddle):
select 
    rm.id as id, 
    rm.created_at, 
    rm.room_id,
    rm.discussion_message_id, 
    dm.text, 
    count(dr.id) as replies
FROM rooms_messages AS rm
INNER JOIN discussions_messages AS dm ON rm.discussion_message_id = dm.id
LEFT JOIN discussions_replies AS dr ON dm.id = dr.discussion_message_id
group by 1,2,3,4,5

If you want to also show the number of messages add count(distinct dm.id) as messages to your SELECT statement Fiddle.

Put all & only what is needed to answer in your post, not just at another page. Avoid social & meta commentary in posts. (Don't write about what you are saying, just say it.) If a question isn't clear don't answer it & don't ask for clarity in posts. Wait until you get enough reputation to comment, don't guess. Indent code reasonably per syntax & semantics. [answer] [ask] [Help] [meta] [meta.se]
